# Display height in bokeh vbar tooltip

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to make a bar chart of some simple data, e.g. a pandas dataframe like this.

```
Cats 4
Dogs 3
Mice 27
```

I would like a tooltip which displays something like this when hovering over a bar:

```
Name: Cats
Count: 4
```

With a bar chart, this worked with

```
hover.tooltips = [
('Name', ' $x'),
('Count', ' @height'),
]
```

I since switched to vbars. What would be the corresponding keyword for @height? Or does it generally not work this way with vbars/hbars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I could make an extra ColumnDataSource like this:

```
hover_help = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    count=[value for value in animals["No"]]
))
```

which yields a list of values for animals. This can then be used for the vbar like this:

```
p.vbar(source=hover_help, bottom=0, x=animal_names, top=animals['No'], color='#18286b', legend=False, **bar_opts)
```

Even if the source is not used as a data source, it can now be used for the tooltip:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ('Name', ' $x'),
    ('Count', ' @count'),
]
```

Comment: This may not work anymore (as of 0.12.10). I am getting a bokeh error: `Supplying a user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods is
not possibe`

Comment: Yes, the new Bokeh version changed a lot... This solution may be out of date. If someone else has a working solution, please update! I'm not really into Bokeh anymore.